# how to update a multi spreadsheet xls file in php on the fly?

Tags: php, xls

I have a sample xls file containing 15 spreadsheets. Each of them has some kind of sample data. I have to update some cell values. 
how can I do that in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) library:

```
$myExcelFile = 'myFile.xls'
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($myExcelFile);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!')


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($myExcelFile);
```

Comment: let's downote the phpexcel creator, i'm sure he doesnt know what he's talking about...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a unified reader/writer package for Excel spreadsheets 
so you'll have to make use of two separate packages, a reader package and a writer one. 
You can try the ExcelReader project available from Google Code or the PHP-ExcelReader package from souceforge and the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package from PEAR, to build something suitable to read the data from the spreadsheets, import it into a database and then editing and save it back as Excel.

cheers

Links:

- http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/
- http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Comment: I beg to differ.... the whole point of the PHPExcel library is to provide a unified reader/writer package for Excel (and other) spreadsheet formats - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/ and http://phpexcel.codeplex.com